# Java thread client Null pointer exception: Do I need to use socket.connect() or socket.connect(null) in order to connect a client to a server?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm creating two program files (one client one server).

Each file has one thread (one thread for server, one thread for client)

At runtime, there is supposed to be only one server, and there is supposed to be multiple and/or potentially infinite number of clients connecting to the server at the same time)

In order to get multiple clients to run, the user opens multiple command prompt / mac terminal windows (each window being one client) (one window being the server, so it requires at least two windows to run)

Once a client is connected, it can send messages (utf-8 strings) to the server. It will also receive from the server all messages sent from the other connected clients (it will not receive messages sent from itself).

The port number I am using to connect is 5344 (localhost).

Screenshot of client error:

[image]

Screenshot of server (no errors):

[image]

The error message is:

```
Exception in thread “Thread-75562” java.lang.NullPointerException at ChatClient$1.run(ChatClient.java:39)
```

The "39" is the line of code (I think) that the error is pointing at.

Screenshot of line 39 in ChatClient.java:

[image]

I have notice that some people use

```
Socket socket = new Socket(host, portNumber);
```

without calling any Socket.connect(host, portNumber); to connect to a server. 
Does socket.connect() ever need to be used to connect a client to a server?

Code of ChatClient.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class ChatClient
{
    private static Socket Socket;
    static int numberOfClients = 0;
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
              //If I wanted to create multiple clients, would this code go here? OR should the new thread creation be outside the while(true) loop?
              while (true)
              {
                  String host = "localhost";
                  int numberOfClients = 0;
                  Thread ChatClient1 = new Thread ()
                  {
                      public void run()
                      {   
                          try
                          {
                              //Client begins, gets port number, listens, connects, prints out messages from other clients
                              int port = 0;
                              int port_1number1 = 0;
                              int numberofmessages = 0;
                              String[] messagessentbyotherclients = null;
                              System.out.println("Try block begins..");
                              System.out.println("Chat client is running");
                              String port_number1= args[0];
                              System.out.println("Port number is: " + port_number1);
                              if(args.length>0)
                              {
                                  port = Integer.valueOf(port_number1);
                              }
                              System.out.println("Listening for connections..");
                              System.out.println( "Listening on port: " + port_number1 );
                              try 
                              {
                                  Socket.connect(null);
                              }
                              catch (IOException e1) 
                              {

                                e1.printStackTrace();
                              }
                              System.out.println("Client has connected to the server");
                              boolean KeepRunning = true;
                              while(KeepRunning)
                              {
                                  for(int i = 0; i < numberOfClients; i++)
                                  {
                                      System.out.println(messagessentbyotherclients);
                                  }
                                  try 
                                  {
                                    //client creates new message from standard input
                                    OutputStream os = Socket.getOutputStream();
                                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                                  }
                                  catch (IOException e)
                                  {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
                                  //creating message to send from standard input
                                  String newmessage = "";
                                  try   
                                  {
                                      // input the message from standard input encoded in UTF-8 string format
                                      BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                                      String line = "";
                                      System.out.println( "Standard input (press enter then control D when finished): " );
                                      while( (line= input.readLine()) != null )     
                                      {
                                          newmessage += line + " ";
                                          input=null;
                                      }
                                  }
                                  catch ( Exception e )
                                  {
                                      System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                                  }
                                  //Sending the message to server
                                  String sendMessage = newmessage;
                                  try 
                                  {
                                    OutputStream os = Socket.getOutputStream();
                                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                                    bw.write(sendMessage + "\n");
                                    bw.flush();
                                  } 
                                  catch (IOException e)
                                  {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
                                  System.out.println("Message sent to server: "+sendMessage);
                              }

                          }
                          finally
                          {

                          }

                      }
                  };
                  ChatClient1.start();    
              }
    }
}
```

Code of ChatServer.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class ChatServer
{
    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Thread ChatServer1 = new Thread () 
        {
            public void run ()
            {   
                System.out.println("Server thread is now running");
                try
                {
                    int port_number1 = 0;
                    int numberOfClients = 0;
                    boolean KeepRunning = true;
                    if(args.length>0)
                    {
                        port_number1 = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Waiting for connections on port " + port_number1);

                    try 
                    {
                         ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
                         socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println( "Listening for connections on port: " + ( port_number1 ) );
                    while(KeepRunning)
                    {
                        //create a list of clients
                        ArrayList<String> ListOfClients = new ArrayList<String>();

                        //connect to client
                        // socket = serverSocket.accept();

                        //add new client to the list, is this the right way to add a new client? or should it be in a for loop or something?
                        ListOfClients.add("new client");
                        numberOfClients += 1;

                        System.out.println("A client has connected. Waiting for message...");
                        ListOfClients.add("new client" + numberOfClients);

                        //reading encoded utf-8 message from client, decoding from utf-8 format 
                        String MessageFromClientEncodedUTF8 = "";
                        BufferedReader BufReader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));  
                        String MessageFromClientDecodedFromUTF8 = BufReader1.readLine();
                        byte[] bytes = MessageFromClientEncodedUTF8.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
                        String MessageFromClientDecodedUTF8 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");


                        //relaying message to every other client besides the one it was from

                        for (int i = 0; i < ListOfClients.size(); i++)
                        {
                            if(ListOfClients.get(i)!="new client")
                            {
                                   String newmessage = null;
                                   String returnMessage = newmessage;
                                   OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                                   OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                                   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                                   bw.write(returnMessage + "\n");
                                   System.out.println("Message sent to client: "+returnMessage);
                                   bw.flush();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        if (socket != null)
                        {
                            socket.close ();
                        }

                    } 
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        };
        ChatServer1.start();
    }
}
```

My question is: How to resolve the error and/or should I delete the socket.connect() while somehow still being able to connect to the server as a client?

Comment: You never create a `Socket`

Comment: @tkausl is that on the client side before the while loop or outside some part of the code I'm not seeing? where do i never create it?

Comment: @tkausl I created a private static socket Socket at the beginning of each file..I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: `Socket.connect` takes a `SocketAddress` according to the documentation.

Comment: `private static Socket socket;` is identical to `private static Socket socket = null;`.  You are not creating anything by merely declaring a field.

Comment: i suggest you to try something similar to this guide https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html